Что или чего в сочетании с "раскрывать нельзя"
Как правильно:
...может раскрыть обо мне то, чего никак раскрывать нельзя
или
может раскрыть обо мне то, что никак раскрывать нельзя.

подумал, и так и так можно, почти нет разницы, единственное -"раскрыть..., раскрывать" - повтор. В негативной форме, наверное, лучше "чего", но не принципиально. "Чего" - менее конкретно, чем "что".

Ясно, спасибо))
